# Run code at startup in using any dotnet hosting model

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am developing library to validate `IOptions<>` at startup. I am using [IStartupFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0) AspNet interface.

My lib depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`. I would like to have unified mechanism which works for any kind of service, i.e. HostedService, AspNet, console etc. I would like to not force user to call any methods at startup, because he is already expected to use  package.

I cannot validate options before service collection is built, because the have to be resolved from DI, so validation needs to happen between DI container is built, and control is passed to actual app.

Is it possible to add such startup validation code which works for all kinds of apps?